# Algebraic conditions of separability

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, hahn-banach-theorem, linear-algebra

Let $X$ be a real vector space (without any norm), and $Y$ be a convex subset of $X$, $0\notin Y$. The goal is to find a hyperplane $L$ passing through 0 such that $Y$ lies in a closed halfspace bounded by $L$. Under which conditions is it always possible? Usual Hahn-Banach theorem requires that $Y$ has a non-empty algebraic interior, i.e. there exists $p\in Y$ such that for any $x\in X$ the point $p+t(x-p)$ belongs to $Y$ for small enough $t>0$. But there are important cases, when the statement is still true, while algebraic interior is empty. Example: $Y$ is a cone of non-negative functions in $L^p$, shifted by any non-zero non-negative function. Are there general algebraic conditions, which cover this case and garantee the existence of separating hyperplane?